# Is there any way to get the domain of the user inside your Microsoft Teams app?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm currently trying to deploy a web app in a Microsoft Teams app (to be used in the personal scope). Currently, every client has a different URL to access its domain specific instance of the web app. Is there any way, in the Teams context probably, to get the domain (name, id...) of the user to redirect him to the proper URL ?
Right now, I only see a `teamId`. But I doubt it can help me here.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Sayali-MSFT. Let's say we have three companies as our clients (Company A, B and C). Right now, they all have different instance of our product as a web app ("ourproductforcompanya.com", "companybourpoduct.com" and "cusesourproduct.com"). In order to redirect them to the correct url when opening the future Teams app, I need to know if a user is logging from Company A Teams domain, Company B Teams domain or Company C Teams domain.

Comment: Using the team turnContext you will get the tenantId.there doesn't seems to be possible to get the domain name.
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoFmz.png